# How to get htpasswd in Docker Registry to work?

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose, .htpasswd

I have been over numerous tutorials and I cannot get htpasswd to work in my private Docker Registry.

Here is my folder structure:

```
├── auth
│   └── htpasswd
├── certs
│   ├── registry.my.domain.crt
│   ├── registry.my.domain.csr
│   └── registry.my.domain.key
├── data
└── docker-compose.yml
```

Maybe it's not important, but I generated my files like this:

In auth folder:

```
htpasswd -Bc htpasswd username
```

In certs folder:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout registry.my.domain.key -out registry.my.domain.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in registry.my.domain.csr -signkey registry.my.domain.key -out registry.my.domain.crt
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  registry:
    container_name: registry
    image: registry:2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - "REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE:/certs/registry.my.domain.crt"
      - "REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY:/certs/registry.my.domain.key"
      - "REGISTRY_AUTH:htpasswd"
      - "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM:Registry"
      - "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH:/auth/htpasswd"
      - "REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true"
    volumes:
      - "./data:/var/lib/registry"
      - "./certs:/certs"
      - "./auth:/auth"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 2048M
```

After I log in to `registry.my.domain/v2/_catalog` it shows all repositories that I uploaded, and it doesn't ask me for authentification.
I can also push and pull to the registry from any machine.

How can I secure it so that it asks for password?

Comment: I think you should remove the " around your env variables

Answer (score 1):

I did the exact same scenario as you and it worked correctly. you can follow the below commands:

1- creating certificate:

```
openssl req \
 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout certs/domain.key \
 -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:registry.my.domain.com" \
 -x509 -days 365 -out certs/domain.crt
```

2- Creating user and password for authentication

```
docker run \
  --entrypoint htpasswd \
  httpd:2 -Bbn testuser testpassword > auth/htpasswd
```

3- My docker compose file

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  registry:
  restart: always
  image: registry:2
  ports:
    - 5000:5000
  environment:
    REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /certs/domain.crt
    REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /certs/domain.key
    REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR: 0.0.0.0:5000
    REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
    REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/htpasswd
    REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry Realm
    VIRTUAL_PORT: 5000
    VIRTUAL_HOST: registry.my.domain.com
    LETSENCRYPT_HOST: registry.my.domain.com
  volumes:
    - /mnt/registry:/var/lib/registry
    - ./certs:/certs
    - ./auth:/auth
```

4- run docker compose

```
docker compose up -d
```

5- Copy certificate (domain.crt) on destination client (node) and execute following commands:

```
sudo cp certs/domain.crt \ 
  /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.my.domain.com:5000/ca.crt
sudo cp certs/domain.crt \
  /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/registry.my.domain.com.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

6- Now, you can login to your private registry

```
docker login -u testuser -p testpassword registry.my.domain:5000
```

7- Testing private registry

```
docker pull busybox
docker tag busybox registry.my.domain.com:5000/mybusybox
docker push registry.my.domain.com:5000/mybusybox
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the syntax on environment variables in the compose file. If you use an array, the separator is an `=` in a string. If you use a map, there's a colon and space between the key and value. See the syntax of yaml files for more details of their syntax.

This:

```yaml
    environment:
      - "REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE:/certs/registry.my.domain.crt"
      - "REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY:/certs/registry.my.domain.key"
      - "REGISTRY_AUTH:htpasswd"
      - "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM:Registry"
      - "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH:/auth/htpasswd"
      - "REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true"
```

should be:

```yaml
    environment:
      - "REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/registry.my.domain.crt"
      - "REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/registry.my.domain.key"
      - "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd"
      - "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry"
      - "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd"
      - "REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true"
```

or

```yaml
    environment:
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /certs/registry.my.domain.crt
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /certs/registry.my.domain.key
      REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/htpasswd
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED: "true"
```